# Run code when new page is created in MediaWiki

Tags: comments, wiki, mediawiki

I want every page on my wiki to end with a `<comments />` tag. How do I automatically add this tag to the end of every page?

NOTE: `comments` tag comes from ArticleComments extension.

Do I have to write my own extension? How do I go about this?

Comment: Did you look at [User:Subfader/Article_Comments](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Subfader/Article_Comments) on mediawiki.org?

Comment: I have managed to do it with comments by editing the skin file, but now I want to do it with categories. That still requires appending a category tag to every page, so the question still applies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at something like the Preloader extension or the MultiBoilerplate extension at the mediawiki home page see if it matches what you need

Comment: The only problem with these is that it's possible to bypass them. I want it to be forcefully appended to the end of the article.

Comment: [Extension:Header Footer](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Header_Footer) maybe? Never tried it myself, but this is what's usually mentioned in similar situations.